# Soapclient wsdl initialize with custom http request header

Tags: php, wsdl, soap-client

I have wsld url.  I have to add custom http request header  to authorize for this  wsdl.  When I try soapclient  as following , I get error.

```
/* userName and password is masked in this question */
$opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
                "userName:xxxxx\r\n".
                "password:xxxxxx\r\n"
        )

);
$streamContext  = stream_context_create($opts);
$cilent = new SoapClient("https://iflyrestest.ibsgen.com:6013/iRes_Booking_WS/services/AvailabilityPort?wsdl" , array('stream_context'    => $streamContext));
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions> in
```

Because response  is like 'You are not authorized to access this URL...'

Also When I try function 'file_get_content()' with same stream_context,  I successfully get  content of this url.

How should I use soapclient for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure it is a basic authentication, then you can simply use the `login` and `password` SoapClient options, instead of stream_context, with your credentials, it should work then.

Comment: @mikeel  Unfortunetly , the wsdl not use http basic authentication. I have to send them via http header